# After inserted selected fields from one table to another, how to insert/update new records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor

I can insert selected fields from Table A to Table B, with `INSERT INTO Table B(planid, testno, sd, testname) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);`, `SQL = "select * from Table A"`and `cursor.execute(SQL)`, but table A will have new records at any time, how to insert new records and update old records? Really appreciate for any advice.

Comment: You say table A and table B, but your query is `Tablename`??? So what do you want? Whenever table A is updated by a DML, you want to run that DML to table B? Or do you want scheduled synchronize table A to table B?

Comment: @Pham X. Bach Hi, I am sorry for omitting something, I want scheduled synchronize table A to table B, but in my case scheduled is not important thing, I just need a correct script firstly, I can use crontab to schedule in Linux system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

----First update existing records:

update tableb set testno=t2.testno, sd=t2.sd, testname=t2.testname
from tableb t1 inner join tablea t2 where t1.planid=t2.planid

----Insert new records
insert into tableb
select * from tablea where planid not in(select planid from tableb)